# Why is DRF Pagination not working with GenericAPISerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1,
}
```

views.py

```
class example(GenericAPIView): 
    queryset = example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        query = request.GET.get('name')
        if query:
            bla = example.objects.filter(name=query)
        else:
            bla = example.objects.all()
        if bla:
            serializer = ExampleSerializer(bla, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Now if I go to the endpoint ?page=1 there are still 5000 records being returned.  Is putting pagination in my settings.py not enough?  Do I need to add pagination specific code to my views?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom pagination :

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage

def get(self, request, format=None):
    query = request.GET.get('name')
    limit = request.query_params.get("limit", 5) #objects per page
    offset = request.query_params.get("offset", 1) #page no
    if query:
        bla = example.objects.filter(name=query)
    else:
        bla = example.objects.all()
    if bla:
        try:
            paginator = Paginator(bla, limit)
        except:
            paginator = Paginator(bla, 10)
        try:
            bl = paginator.page(offset)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            bl = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            bl = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        count = paginator.count

        next = None if not bl.has_next() else bl.next_page_number()
        previous = None if not bl.has_previous() else bl.previous_page_number()

        serializer = ExampleSerializer(bl, many=True)

        data = {"count": count, 'next': next, 'previous': previous, 'results': serializer.data}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```